# pandas time-series data preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, visualization

I have dataframe look likes this :

```
> dt
    text    timestamp
0   a   2016-06-13 18:00
1   b   2016-06-20 14:08
2   c   2016-07-01 07:41
3   d   2016-07-11 19:07
4   e   2016-08-01 16:00
```

And I want to summarise every month's data like:

```
> dt_month
count   timestamp
0   2   2016-06
1   2   2016-07
2   1   2016-08
```

the original dataset(`dt`) can be generated by:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'text': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    'timestamp': ['2016-06-13 18:00', '2016-06-20 14:08', '2016-07-01 07:41', '2016-07-11 19:07', '2016-08-01 16:00']}
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And are there any ways can plot a time-frequency plot by `dt_month` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby by `timestamp` column converted [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df.text.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.to_period('m'))
              .size()
              .rename('count')
              .reset_index())

  timestamp  count
0   2016-06      2
1   2016-07      2
2   2016-08      1
```